# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

I am trying to add jquery fullcalendar to mvc project. I downloaded jquery.fullcalendar from Nuget Manager. And then I added below simple codes to viewpage. But it is not displayed and when i check the errors it gives me :

```
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (Calendar:62)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery.min.js:2)
```

My codes :

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="~/Content/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/moment.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/fullcalendar.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/gcal.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/lang/tr.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="calendar"></div>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            selectable: true
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone help me? i followed the Basic Usage Doc but it still doesn't work.

I think my paths are correct you can check here :[FullCalendar MVC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7GK2.png)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure to correctly include the FullCalendar.js and its scripts ? Because the reason for getting this error is often that the scripts are not included correctly in the project.

Comment: I also included like that : <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.3.1/fullcalendar.min.css' />   
<script src='https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.3.1/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.3.1/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.3.1/lib/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.3.1/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>  It is still not working

Comment: Can you delete the every .js file except jquery-3.1.1.js, moment.js, fullcalendar.js ? If It didn't work, add jquery-ui.custom.min.js after the jquery.js

Answer (score 0):

**Hi i think you have Problem in script path or css path because i was do same as you in my code it was running very well**

[Please see this link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/23o8yi)

**dont see code controller and model its mvc view just see html page and script.. 
i just do copy your code and paste it.. if you have any query then tell me. or accept it then do right**

Comment: I think my paths are correct. I added screenshot in my post. Can you check. What did i do wrong?

Comment: Still you getting same error? or something another one ? can you try to put same as my path in link because its totally online path if is working then we find another way..

Comment: Yes  i am getting same error. But when I put it online link it is working : [https://dotnetfiddle.net/XL9sAt](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XL9sAt)

Comment: i think something miss-match in this script..if possible then again download that script and css and replace..i hope it will be work..

Comment: It is not working. I also tried to add fullcalender in new empty mvc project but it is not working. What should i do?